# Scrapy: extract from multiple elements with encoding and POST as JSON array

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, scrapy

I am scraping a weather site and need to extract comments from a table cell and POST them as a JSON array to a remote API.

Here is the markup:

```
<td>
    <p>Temperature is cold (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).</p>
    <p>Temperature is very warm (> 60 degrees C / 140 degrees F).</p>
    <p>Temperature is cold (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).</p>
</td>
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
comments = []
cmnts = sel.xpath('td//p/text()').extract()

for cmnt in cmnts:
    comments.append(cmnt)

item['comments'] = comments

r = requests.post(api_url, data = json.dumps(dict(item)))
```

This somewhat works but it has lots of "\r\n" strings in the output and anything after the "<" symbol gets stripped out. Here is the output from the above code:

```
[
   "Temperature is cold (\r\n \r\n ",
   "Temperature is very warm (> 60 degrees C / 140 degrees F)."
   "Temperature is cold (\r\n \r\n ",
]
```

Any ideas on how I can get an array of "clean" (i.e. no returns) and "encoded" results?

Comment: This is actually a broken html, `<` should be `&lt;` instead. Are you ok with `BeautifulSoup` solution? (it is much more lenient if a right parser chosen).

Comment: Sorry @alecxe we are relatively invested into scrapy at the moment so a switch to BeautifulSoup is out of the question.

Comment: Well, you would need to preprocess the html you currently have.  You can combine scrapy and beautifulsoup. For example, in the `parse()` callback parse the html with the `BeautifulSoup` and pass the fixed html to the scrapy selector instance.

Comment: Also, where this html is coming from?

Answer (score 3):

As @alecxe suggests in the comments above, lxml's default parser can't seem to handle this HTML input well, and a solution is to parse it with a more forgiving parser, like BeautifulSoup or html5lib

lxml can in fact use different parsers and still give you the same XPath methods.

Using BeautifulSoup parser:

```
In [1]: from lxml.html import soupparser, html5parser

In [2]: html = """<td>
    <p>Temperature is cold (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).</p>
    <p>Temperature is very warm (> 60 degrees C / 140 degrees F).</p>
    <p>Temperature is cold (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).</p>
</td>
"""

In [3]: doc = soupparser.fromstring(html)

In [4]: for p in doc.xpath('//p'):
    print p.xpath('normalize-space()')
   ...:     
Temperature is cold (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).
Temperature is very warm (> 60 degrees C / 140 degrees F).
Temperature is cold (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).
```

Using html5lib parser (you'll have to add XHTML namespace in your XPath calls):

```
In [5]: doc = html5parser.fromstring(html)

In [6]: for p in doc.xpath('//xhtml:p', namespaces={"xhtml": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}):
    print p.xpath('normalize-space()')
   ...:     
Temperature is cold (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).
Temperature is very warm (> 60 degrees C / 140 degrees F).
Temperature is cold (< 4 degrees C / 40 degrees F).

In [7]:
```

And your Scrapy callback code would become:

```
doc = soupparser.fromstring(response.body)

comments = []
cmnts = doc.xpath('td//p')

for cmnt in cmnts:
    comments.append(cmnt.xpath('normalize-space(.)'))

item['comments'] = comments

r = requests.post(api_url, data = json.dumps(dict(item)))
```